# How to automatically replace a specific word with different one, when it is typed in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So for a joke in my office, I am trying to write a script that will change my friend's name to something else whenever he types it into our shared google sheets spreadsheet.
I got as far as this code that changes everything typed into something else but I would like it to be specifically his name that triggers the script.

Could someone quickly finish it for me? (below is the attempted code)

Much appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sh=e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col=e.range.getColumn();
  var row=e.range.getRow();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' )
  {
    sh.getRange(row,col).setValue('horse');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace the edited cell includes the specific value with the other specific value.
- For example, when the search value and the replace value are `foo` and `bar`, respectively, when `sample foo sample` is put to a cell, you want to achieve the cell value to `sample bar sample`.
- You want to achieve this using OnEdit trigger.

In this case, I would like to propose to use TextFinder. I thought that when TextFinder is used, the script might be simpler. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var fromValue = "foo";  // Please set the search value.
  var toValue = "bar";  // Please set the replace value.

  var range = e.range;
  var textFinder = range.createTextFinder(fromValue);
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || !textFinder.findNext()) return;
  textFinder.replaceWith(toValue);
}
```

- When you use this script, please put a value including `foo` to a cell. By this, the script is run.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: @Marco Parasiliti Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.